# Slick implicit parameter 'tables' with generated tables

Tags: scala, slick, codegen, slick-codegen

### The simple version

What's the preferred way to import and use generated Slick tables?

### The detailed version and what I've tried

I used Slick 3.1.1 codegen to generate a `Tables.scala` from a MySQL (MariaDB) schema.

`Tables.scala` begins with this:

```
// AUTO-GENERATED Slick data model
/** Stand-alone Slick data model for immediate use */
object Tables extends {
    val profile = slick.driver.MySQLDriver
} with Tables
```

What's the best way to use these classes? As per the [Slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/code-generation.html#standalone-use):

> The file contains an object Tables from which the code can be imported for use right away. ... The file also contains a trait Tables which can be used in the cake pattern.

... I've tried variations on [this example](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example/blob/master/src/main/scala/Example.scala)

```
import Tables._
import Tables.profile.api._
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend

class Test(s: String)(implicit db: Database) {
    def exec[T](action: DBIO[T])(implicit db: Database): T =
            Await.result(db run action)
    def run: Unit = exec(((ATable filter (_.id)).result)
}
object Test {
    implicit val db = Database.forURL(url, user, password)
    new Test("")
}
```

I get a compile error wherever I reference the class ATable:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter tables: Tables
```

I don't even see `tables` in `Tables.scala`. How do I get everything I need in scope to use my generated Slick classes?

Comment: Do you have "import kokellab.db.core.Tables" somewhere?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn Thanks! I had just removed the package names for simplicity. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the example to work: `Tables._` and `Tables.profile.api._` just need to be imported inside the class with an implicit `Database` available.

```
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend

class Test(s: String)(implicit db: Database) {
    import Tables._
    import Tables.profile.api._

    def exec[T](action: DBIO[T])(implicit db: Database): T =
            Await.result(db run action)
    def run: Unit = exec(((ATable filter (_.id)).result)
}
object Test {
    implicit val db = Database.forURL(url, user, password)
    new Test("")
}
```